# Сравнение изображения и поиск похожести AForge.Imaging

Tags: c#, изображения, распознавание

Я что-то вообще понять не могу как это работает.
Использую AForge.Imaging
У меня есть 1 карта большая

[image: Одна большая карта 6s]

и две маленькие которые я ищу относительно большого шаблона.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.90f); стоит 0.90f

далее я хочу получить все значение что-бы  понять какая карта имеет бОльшее значение совпадения.
И что я получаю?!
А получаю я на 8s - 0.96433.
А на 6s - 0.95432.

То есть получается, что 8s (больше похожа на шаблон)
Что я не так делают!?

```
public bool test(Image largePicBox, Image smallPicBox, string filename)
        {
            

              Bitmap largeImage = ConvertToFormat(largePicBox, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
              Bitmap smallImage = ConvertToFormat(smallPicBox, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

           
            ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.90f);

           
            TemplateMatch[] matches = tm.ProcessImage(smallImage, largeImage);

            if (matches.Length > 0)
            {
               
                TemplateMatch match = matches[0];

                person[c2] = new Cards();
                person[c2].maxsize = match.Similarity;
                person[c2].filename = filename;
                c2++;
                return true;
                 
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
               
            }


public Bitmap ConvertToFormat(Image image, PixelFormat format)
        {
            Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, format);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(copy))
            {
                gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, copy.Width, copy.Height));
            }
            return copy;
        }
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1241912/373567?

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Это другой метод.

Comment: Это был не ответ, а вопрос.

Comment: У меня практического личное обучение , тот метод , вполне себя оправдал, теперь я хочу понять почему тут ничего не получается. Приму любой ответ или помощь